# How to determine which MasterPage an error was generated from?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, webforms, master-pages

We have a large ASP WebForms application and I'm trying to make the error page look better and be more helpful.  We have several MasterPages, one of them is for displaying content inside an iframe in a modal window we open via JavaScript.  Right now if an error occurs in one of these modal pages the modal iframe gets redirected to our `~/Error.aspx` page with contains the normal site design  - inside the modal which is on top of the site design.  It looks quite dumb.

What I'd like to do is determine the masterpage of the page that generated the error, and then change the masterpage of the Error page so that it does not repeat the design from inside the iframe.  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of debugging, I seem to have found a way to do what I want in VB, although it's a  bit hacky...

```vb
Public Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Attempt to determine if this error came from a page displayed within a modal
    Dim page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler, _BasePage)
    If page IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim masterPageFile As String = page.MasterPageFile
        'The best we can to here is to find the masterpage and see if it
        'contains the string "modal" since that's normally how we name these things
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(masterPageFile) AndAlso masterPageFile.Contains("modal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            '==============
            'We did it!!!
            '==============
         End If
    Else
        'Either `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler` or `Page` is `Nothing`, so this might be a 404 or other error.
        'Let's see if there are other ways to determine if we are in a modal.

        Dim pathToAttemptedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path
        Dim referrerUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath

        If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathToAttemptedFile) AndAlso pathToAttemptedFile.Contains(tokenInUrlPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) OrElse
           (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(referrerUrl) AndAlso referrerUrl.Contains(tokenInUrlPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) Then
            '==============
            'We did it!!!
            '==============
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```